# How do I tell how many people are still using older versions of R?

Tags: r, version

I'm evaluating whether it's worth retaining support for old versions of R in packages that I maintain, which adds a maintenance overhead.  As such, I'd like to estimate how many people are still using R3.5.

This sort of data is easy to find for [web browsers](https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-market-share); and I know that RStudio compile download statistics for packages.  But is there a comparable source of data for who is using (and thus presumably updating packages in) older versions of R?

Comment: This discussion seems relevant https://blog.r-hub.io/2022/09/12/r-dependency/, You could use cranlogs to see which versions of R are being dowloaded https://r-hub.github.io/cranlogs/. It doest seem that the [cran logs](http://cran-logs.rstudio.com/) published by R studio includes R version with package downloads. You could download those CSV files and calculate used yourself if you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems raw data is available from http://cran-logs.rstudio.com/ but the data is not grouped by R version. Here we can download the results for a particular day and see how many requests for packages came from different R versions.

```
options(timeout = max(300, getOption("timeout")))

day <- "2023-04-03"
year <- as.POSIXlt(day)$year + 1900
gzfile <- paste0(day, '.csv.gz')
fileurl <- paste0('http://cran-logs.rstudio.com/', year, '/', gzfile)
download.file(fileurl, gzfile)

dd <- readr::read_csv(gzfile)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dd %>% 
  filter(!is.na(r_version) & r_version != "vosonSML") %>% 
  count(r_version) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(r_version, n) + 
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: R versions accessing CRAN on 4/3/2023]

This site only tracks requests that go to the RStudio CRAN mirror (which is the default so it's probably most requests) but it does ignore other CRAN mirrors. This summary also treats each requests as independent but it's likely that the same computer was installing more than on package on a given day due to package dependencies and such.

It's clear that most people are at least running 4.0 but there is a long tail of versions. For a more representative sample, you will probably want to sample across different dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the cranlogs package to get this data, e.g.

```r
cranlogs::cran_downloads(when = "last-week", "R") |>
   dplyr::filter(version == "3.5.0")
```

```
         date version  os count
1  2023-04-14   3.5.0 src     1
2  2023-04-14   3.5.0 win     3
3  2023-04-14   3.5.0 osx     1
4  2023-04-15   3.5.0 osx     1
5  2023-04-16   3.5.0 src     1
6  2023-04-16   3.5.0 win     2
7  2023-04-17   3.5.0 win     2
8  2023-04-17   3.5.0 osx     1
9  2023-04-18   3.5.0 osx     1
10 2023-04-19   3.5.0 src     1
11 2023-04-19   3.5.0 osx     1
12 2023-04-19   3.5.0 win     2
13 2023-04-20   3.5.0 osx     1
```

Comment: I think this reports new downloads of R itself, so will under-count cases where R was installed long ago by an administrator and cannot be updated. (No version information is returned when the `packages` argument is set.)